# a hrefからwindow.openを使用したコードにしたい。

Tags: javascript, html

いつもお世話になっております。

下記URLを参考にしてRSSアプリを作成中です。

■参考URL
http://news.7zz.jp/ajax/2447.html

サイト内の118行目のコードについて
このままリンクを開こうとすると、アプリ内で開いてしまい、iosだと前のページへ戻れなくなってしまいます。(_blankでもダメでした。)

Window.openを使うコードに変更したいのですが
下記コードの場合は、どのように修正すれば良いでしょうか？
Targetは「_system」で起動したいです。

■変えたいコード(118行目)

```
+ '<a href="'+ entries[l]['link'] + '">' + entries[l]['title'] + '</a>'
```

こちらのように変更してみましたが上手く行きませんでした。。。

```
+ '<a href="#" onclick="window.open('+ entries[l]['link'] + ','_system')">' + entries[l]['title'] + '</a>'
```

無知で申し訳ないですが、ご教示をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

文字列がシングルクォーテーションで囲ってあるので、その中にシングルクォーテーションを書くときは`\`(￥マーク)を先頭に付けます。

また、こちらも参照されるとよろしいかと思います。

[特殊な文字の入力(エスケープシーケンス)](http://www.ajaxtower.jp/js/num/index2.html)

```
+ '<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\''+ entries[l]['link'] + '\',\'_system\')">' + entries[l]['title'] + '</a>'
```

Comment: 迅速なご回答ありがとうございます！
想定していた動作になりました！